# How to change the OnMouseReleaseEvent for multiple Buttons?

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling

I am trying to figure out how to change the OnMouseReleaseEvent for multiple Buttons at once. The application is an on screen piano where I want to remove the release event so that the played note sustains rather than shuts off after a short click.

My code snippet worked for one key:

```
@FXML
public void changeOnMouseRelease(){
        if (getOriginalEvent() == null) {
            setOriginalEvent(keyC.getOnMouseReleased());
        }
        if (getOriginalEvent() == keyC.getOnMouseReleased()) {
            keyC.setOnMouseReleased(event -> {
                System.out.println("Mouserelease-Event empty \n");
            });
        } else keyC.setOnMouseReleased(getOriginalEvent());
    }
}
```

These are the getter and setter for the original event:

```
private void setOriginalEvent(EventHandler originalEvent){
    this.originalEvent = originalEvent;
}

private EventHandler getOriginalEvent(){
    return this.originalEvent;
}
```

When I try this it doesn't work:

```
@FXML
public void changeOnMouseRelease(){
    for(Button b : pianoKeys) {  // pianoKeys is just an array of the 13 piano buttons
        if (getOriginalEvent() == null) {
            setOriginalEvent(b.getOnMouseReleased());
        }
        if (getOriginalEvent() == b.getOnMouseReleased()) {
            b.setOnMouseReleased(event -> {
                System.out.println("Mouserelease-Event empty \n");
            });
        } else b.setOnMouseReleased(getOriginalEvent());
    }
}
```

I am assuming it has something to do with the getter/setter but I am not sure how to handle this properly.

Comment: Can you please show the onMouseRelease implementation for Button and elaborate why you want to remove/add it a little bit more? Why don't you just have a `if(needsExecution)` int the onMouseReleaseEvent that skips the logic if false, instead of doing so complicated things.

Answer (score 0):

By adding a `MouseEvent` parameter to the event handler, you can use this information to retrieve the `Button` that was pressed. You could associate information that allows you to choose how to handle the key press with the `Button`, e.g. using `userData`:

#### controller

```
@FXML
private void onMouseReleased(MouseEvent event){
    Button b = (Button) event.getSource();
    System.out.println("released key "+b.getUserData());
}


@FXML
private void onMousePressed(MouseEvent event){
    Button b = (Button) event.getSource();
    System.out.println("pressed key "+b.getUserData());
}
```

#### fxml

```xml
...
<Button onMousePressed="#onMousePressed" onMouseReleased="#onMouseReleased" userData="D#" />
...
```

---

This removes the need to loop through the buttons.